# Token Approval Removal

Tags: transactions, wallets, code

Someone has gotten multiple Token Approvals on my account, likely through my own fault, but I cannot tell when.

they have token approvals on MATIC and ETH.  so that when I transfer ETH into remove the approval they steal it.

Is it possible to write code to transfer ETH to a wallet then almost immediately revoke the token approval?